# Creating folder shortcuts or checking in folder shortcuts in Accurev

Tags: directory, shortcut, accurev

We are using Accurev in our build environment. We are trying to check in a 3rd party SDK that contains folder shortcuts. But Accurev is not allowing us to promote folder shortcuts.

Has anyone else using Accurev run into this issue? If yes, how did you resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving while doing the promote?  I just created a folder shortcut and was able to add/promote the file in AccuRev.

Comment: "Cannot add link (link target must be an existing element in this workspace): /path"

Comment: We are basically trying to integrate the Crashlytics library to our iPhone code and promote the change in Accurev. We are using AccuRev 6.0.1. Crashlytics library has symbolic links. And we get the above error when we tried to promote the change in Accurev.

Comment: You might want to contact AccuRev's tech support regarding that error.

Comment: That error means the target of the link isn't "kept" in the Accurev depot.  First adding the target should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can keep symbolic links in Linux and I've noticed that on Windows they appear as folder shortcuts when you update the workspace. However, I've never added them myself.

You could try the:

```
accurev ln
```

command documented in the [Accurev CLI](http://72.3.132.200/download/docs/4.6.0cc_books/AccuRev_User_CLI.pdf).